# Displaying Item's (Icons) evenly in Toolbar

Tags: android, toolbar

I want to display all five Icons evenly in my toolbar. But currently there is only one icon displayed on the left hand side of the toolbar, the rest of the space inside the toolbar is empty. I tried to manage the items with a Method called `setupEvenlyDistributedToolbar`.

I got this Code in MainActivity:

```
package com.example.timomichel.myapplication;

import android.content.ClipData;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Point;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.view.Display;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private Toolbar toolbar;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar) ;
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    setupEvenlyDistributedToolbar();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.items, menu);
    return true;
}

public void setupEvenlyDistributedToolbar() {
    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    Point size = new Point();
    display.getSize(size);
    int width = size.x;
    int height = size.y;

    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    toolbar.inflateMenu(R.menu.items);
    toolbar.setContentInsetsAbsolute(0, 0);

    int childCount = toolbar.getChildCount();
    int screenWidth = (width/5);

    Toolbar.LayoutParams toolbarParams = new Toolbar.LayoutParams(screenWidth, Toolbar.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    for (int i = 0; i < childCount; i++) {
        View childView = toolbar.getChildAt(i);
        childView.setLayoutParams(toolbarParams);
    }

}

}
```

My XML file for MainActivity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      tools:context="com.example.timomichel.myapplication.MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello World!" />

    <include layout="@layout/toolbar" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is my XML for the toolbar:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/black">


</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

And finally the XML for the items in the menu folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<item
    android:id="@+id/profile"
    app:showAsAction="always"
    android:icon="@drawable/android_icon"
    android:title="profile" />

<item
    android:id="@+id/friends"
    app:showAsAction="always"
    android:icon="@drawable/android_icon"
    android:title="friends"/>

<item
    app:showAsAction="always"
    android:icon="@drawable/android_icon"
    android:title="maps"/>

<item
    app:showAsAction="always"
    android:icon="@drawable/android_icon"
    android:title="events" />

<item
    app:showAsAction="always"
    android:icon="@drawable/android_icon"
    android:title="Settings" />


</menu>
```

Hope you can also help me with this question, thanks a lot!